# Object Orientation with 2 Lists

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, linked-list

I have 2 Linked lists:

```
List A: 
Node1 contains Object1
Node 2 contains Object2
Node 3 contains Object3
```

this second linked list contains the *same objects*;

```
List B: 
Node1 contains Object3
Node2 contains Object2
Node3 contains Object1
```

If I want to delete, let's say Node1 in List 2, will Object 3 still exist in List1?
How do I implement this?

Please ask for any clarification necessary.

Comment: Why the instant downvote??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this site is more for specific questions, you haven't included any attempts or structure yourself. We can't do it for you, we can only help once you get a problem (and you can't solve it with google or searching, this is important!)

Comment: It's a theoretical object orientation quesiton. Heaven forbid.

Comment: I do appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: What are you looking to implement? Node deletion in a linked list? Hint for you: your linked lists don't contain objects. They contain pointers to objects.

Comment: That's what I'm getting at. Excellent hint. So essentially I'm able to create a Node object that contains a pointer to another object and in deleting the node, the pointer is deleted but not the object?

Comment: If you're able to formulate a response in the form of an answer, I'd be glad to give you the check.

Comment: Yep, that's right. I'm on mobile right now, and don't have the patience to write a good answer on a soft keyboard, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked lists do not store objects. They  have the pointers to the objects. so if you delete a node from list1, it no way affects the node in list2, because only the pointer to the object is removed from list1, and the object still remains in the memory for the other list to access.